# Run angular universal application in docker container

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

```
# common base image for development and 
FROM node:10.15.3 AS 
WORKDIR /app

ARG SC_NPM_TOKEN
ENV SC_NPM_TOKEN="${SC_NPM_TOKEN}"

# dev image contains everything needed for testing, development and building
FROM base AS development
COPY . /app

# install all dependencies and add source code
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9

# builder runs unit tests and linter, then builds production code 
FROM development as builder
RUN npm run build:ssr --prod --output-path=dist
# RUN ls -ls ../
# RUN ls -ls .
# RUN pwd

# release includes bare minimum required to run the app, copied from builder
FROM base AS release
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /app/dist
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json /app/

ENV NODE_ENV "production"
ENV PORT 3000

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run ", "serve:ssr"]
```

When I use this Dockerfile, the container can be build and the nodejs application is started as well. If I try to access the / route, the following error is thrown: `Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/app/dist/browser"`.

I took a look inside of the container and saw that the files are stored in /app/app/. How can there be a second app directory? If I move the files into the /app directory, everything works fine. As I don't understand how the second app directory is created, I can't seem to fix the Dockerfile. I added a couple of debug commands, but I can't see the second app directory when the container is build.

Comment: How are you running the container?  (Do you have a `docker run -v` or Docker Compose `volumes:` option hiding the `/app` tree from the image?)

Comment: You might be right. I got the image working on my local machine. As soon as I build it with a github action and start it with Rancher, it breaks. Can't find any volume or something like that, any other guess?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what the issue is, but we found a workaround. The problem only occurs, when the container is build via the action defined in the github repo. As soon as we duplicated the repository (Create new Repo on github, Delete .git from project, Push to new repo), the new automatically build container just worked. Might be a caching issue, but because of limited time we are just happy that it works for now.